# Mysql select Query Not Working properly

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT * FROM `customers` where warranty_end BETWEEN '01/12/2017' AND '31/12/2017'
```

the above one is my query, in `warranty_end` column content is `30/12/2018`.

But the query resulting Row From Database.

[image]

Comment: What is the data type of warranty_end column?

Comment: varchar(255) @Imran

Comment: `varchar` is string, not date. As `varchar`, `30/12/2018` is just a bunch of letters, it has nothing to do with December 12, 2018. Use [`DATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-types.html) to store dates.

Comment: Convert `warranty_end` to date using `STR_TO_DATE(warranty_end, '%d/%m/%Y') ` and you are done

Comment: @axiac If `warranty_end` were ISO text, then it still should have worked.  But yes much better to store in a date column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your `warranty_end` column is text, and furthermore you are storing your dates there is a non ISO format.  One workaround here would be to convert the text dates into actual dates using `STR_TO_DATE`:

```
SELECT *
FROM customers
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(warranty_end, '%d/%m/%Y') BETWEEN '2017-12-01' AND '2017-12-31';
```

Note here that the `BETWEEN` clause in fact uses ISO date literals.

Moving forward a much better option would be to store your warranty end dates in a date column, e.g. `datetime`.